# git branch -a --no-merged master & 'git branch -r' returns differnt remote branches on two machines

Tags: git

On a weekly basis on before we build our weekly package I run this command to see if there are any unmerged branches.  I am mostly looking for branches on the remote/origin

```
git branch -a --no-merged master
```

This week, the results that I get are missing branches that I know have been pushed back to the remotes/origin.  If another delveloper runs this same command he sees the missing branches from remotes/origin.  I also have a second copy of repository on my unix share and that one works fine too.

I noticed a similar problems with

```
 git branch -r
```

Based on what I see in the git log my repository is up to date. The branches that are missing are a few weeks old.  Is there something else that would keep this from being up to date?

Comment: I assume you've done a git fetch recently?

Comment: Yes..  But I think I found some sort of issue.  I had asked the other developer on my team(who did see the commit on a remote branch to merge it) and he had an error spit back that it couldnt find the reference.  He re-pushed and all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually turned out to be some issue on how the commit was pushed to the origin.  I had original developer try to merge his changes from the remote and though he saw a reference to the remote commit the merge failed.  I will chaulk this up to some other git error.